# Geometric meaning of $D_n/\langle r^d\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$.
Then obviously, $\langle r^d\rangle$ is a normal subgroup, so we may take the quotient$D_n/\langle r^d\rangle$ . It is not hard to show that this is isomorphic to $D_d$.

But what is the geometric meaning of this isomorphism? How do I visualize this? Do we start from an $n$-gon and end up with a $d$-gon?

edit: $D_n = \langle r,s\,\mid\,r^n=s^2=1, rs=sr^-1\rangle$, the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $D_n$?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct, we start with and $n$-gon and end up with a $d$-gon.  One way to think of this is to consider just the rotations (subgroup generated by $r$).  We can think of $r$ as rotating the $n$-gon by $360/n$ degrees.  Of course, that means that applying $r$ $n$-times results a one full rotation of the $n$-gon.  When we mod out by $\left<r^d\right>$, we are saying that applying $r$ $d$-times is the identity, ie, it results in one full rotation.  So the subgroup generated $r\left<r^d\right>$ has order $d$.  This yields the presentation

\begin{equation}
D_n/\left<r^d\right> = \left< r\left<r^d\right>, s\left<r^d\right> \;|\;  \left(r\left<r^d\right>\right)^d = \left(s\left<r^d\right>\right)^2 = 1,\; \left(r\left<r^d\right>\right)\left(s\left<r^d\right>\right) = \left(s\left<r^d\right>\right)\left(r\left<r^d\right>\right)^{-1} \right>
\end{equation}
which is a presentation of $D_d$.